# Dismiss DialogFragment in MVVMCross

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

In the **FundamentalView.cs**, I have click event which triggers a fragment from the bottom of the view with having options (adding a new person and new calculations).

```
 var addButton = view.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.addButton);
 addButton.Click += OnAddButtonClick;

 void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
   var dialog = new CardDialogView();
   dialog.ViewModel = new CardDialogViewModel();
   dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "CardDialogView");        
 }
```

**CardDialogView.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_computer"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Calculation"
        local:MvxBind="Click NewCalculationCommand"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dash_add_head"
        android:drawablePadding="28dp"
        android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="New Person" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**CardDialogView.cs**

```
public class CardDialogView : MvxDialogFragment<CardDialogViewModel>
{
   public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
   {
       ......
       return dialog ;
   }
}
```

[image]

When I click on the textview, it opens the **NewItemViewModel**. So far, so good, but **CardDialogView** (dialog) still appears, I wonder how to dismiss dialog.

**CardDialogViewModel.cs**

```
public class CardDialogViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

    public ICommand NewCalculationCommand
    {
        get
        {
         return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<NewItemViewModel>(new { date = DateTime.Now }));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you can do. In CardDialogViewModel add a new property `DialogVisible` and set it to false when `NewCalculationCommand` is executed:

```
public class CardDialogViewModel : MvxViewModel
{

private bool dialogVisible;

public bool DialogVisible
{
    get {return dialogVisible;}
    set {dialogVisible=value; RaisePropertyChanged(()=> DialogVisible));}
}

public ICommand NewCalculationCommand
{
    get
    {
         return new MvxCommand(() => {
            ShowViewModel<NewItemViewModel>(new { date = DateTime.Now });
            DialogVisible=false;);
        }
    }
}
```

Inside `FundamentalView` watch for `DialogVisible` change and close the dialog:

```
CardDialogView dialog = null;
CardDialogViewModel model = new CardDialogViewModel();
void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    model.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) =>
    {
        if(args.PropertyName == "DialogVisible" && !model.DialogVisible)
        {
            dialog.Dismiss();
        }
    }
}

void OnAddButtonClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   dialog = new CardDialogView();
   dialog.ViewModel = model;
   dialog.Show(((MainView)Activity).SupportFragmentManager, "CardDialogView");        
}
```

There may be some types in the code but I think general idea is easy to understand.

Comment: @hotspring  - I fixed the code in OnAddButtonClick to use fields from FundamentalView

Comment: The second portion of your code, which start with `CardDialogView dialog = null;`, is it in the `NewItemViewModel`?

Comment: @hotspring: It's inside FundamentalView. That is where you have OnAddButtonClick right?

Comment: What if `CardDialogViewModel model = new CardDialogViewModel(string x, string y);` where x and y is not available at the time of the initialization

Comment: @hotspring: You can set them via properties in OnAddButtonClick